# iOS firebase observer delays observing the changes in the node

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I have one function to get the realtime location updates of the selected user.

And in that function , i need to call the current status and history of that selected user from the firebase.

So, the problem is when I start my observer for location updates only , it's fine and it's great . 
I get the value from firebase observer.

But , when i make a call for current status and history of that selected user , I am getting the delay in my firebase realtime observer .

---

I don't understand how come call to another firebase is affecting our realtime observer code.

Guys any suggestions,
I tried dispatching to background for current status /history call but still no luck.

Left me hopeless and clueless.

**Added:**
I am getting current status and realtime observers from the same node.
So , does this happens that same node is observing and same time if another firebase call is made to same node , is it colliding ???

**UPDATED**

Firebase function to get current status :

```
FIRDatabaseReference().child("personal").child(userUUID).child("realtime")
            .observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
            //print(snapshot.key)
            if snapshot.exists(){
                let location = LocationParser(dict: snapshot.value as! [String : AnyObject])?.location
                completion(location)
            }else{
                completion(nil)
            }
        }){ (error) in
            completion(nil)
            debugPrint(error.localizedDescription)
        }
```

Firebase function to observe location (continuously):

```
FIRDatabaseReference().child("personal").child(userUUID).child("realtime")
        .observe(.value) { (snapshot:FIRDataSnapshot) in

        print("\nOBSERVER FROM FIREBASE FIRED")

        if let value = snapshot.value as? [String:AnyObject] {
            if let location = LocationParser(dict: value)?.location {
                //we cannot save location to our database
                //sharedFirebaseManager.saveLocationHistoric(LocationParser(dict: value)!)
                result(success(location))
            }
        }
    }
```

**QUESTION:**

I am calling both from the same controller and I see continuous observer delays on calling another firebase function call. 
Any clue.

Comment: This question is difficult to answer without any code. You should add the code for both Firebase queries so they can be analyzed. If I had to take a stab in the dark I'd look into two things. Are you using the same database reference for the current and observation status? You might want to try using separate references for both I'm not sure if this matters but if you remove the observer after the current status check it could be affecting the other observer?. Additionally, you might want to look into transaction blocks they are used for concurrent updates to the database.

Comment: @DoesData : please review my functions , as I think they are pretty straightforward. 
Cannot guess anything why I get delay in my continuous observer.

Comment: @Frank van Pufflen , is there any possibility of firebase call collision. Can't get any clue on this.